# How to stop a cycling thread

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I have a cycling threading method like this:

```
def make_periodic(self, method, period_sec, *args):
    method(*args)
    parameters = [method, period_sec] + list(args)
    threading.Timer(period_sec, self.make_periodic, parameters).start()
```

What is the best way to stop the the cycling of a method of one type?

For example:

```
import threading


class TestThreading:
    PERIOD = 5

    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 0
        self.text = "t"

    def method_1(self):
        print self.number
        self.number += 1

    def method_2(self, text):
        print self.text
        self.text += text

    def make_periodic(self, method, period_sec, *args):
        method(*args)
        parameters = [method, period_sec] + list(args)
        threading.Timer(period_sec, self.make_periodic, parameters).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = TestThreading()
    test.make_periodic(test.method_1, TestThreading.PERIOD)
    test.make_periodic(test.method_2, TestThreading.PERIOD, "t")

    # stops the cycling of method_2, but the method_1 continues
    test.stop_threading(test.method_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep a reference for each timer in a dictionary: `my_dict["method_name"] = timer`. In that case when you decide to stop the timer just call `my_dict["method_name"].cancel()`.